# ms 2010 vb to move email to a different mailbox and subfolder

Tags: vba, outlook

I am looking to move emails from a folder to the deleted folder of the below mailbox. I get a "compile error: variable not defined" message, where have I gone wrong?

```
Sub MoveToFolder(folderName)

 mailboxNameString = "Mailbox - David Beach"

 Dim olApp As New Outlook.Application
 Dim olNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
 Dim olCurrExplorer As Outlook.Explorer
 Dim olCurrSelection As Outlook.Selection

 Dim olDestFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
 Dim olCurrMailItem As MailItem
 Dim m As Integer

 Set olNameSpace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set olCurrExplorer = olApp.ActiveExplorer
 Set olCurrSelection = olCurrExplorer.Selection

 Set olDestFolder = olNameSpace.Folders(mailboxNameString).Folders(folderName)

 For m = 1 To olCurrSelection.Count
    Set olCurrMailItem = olCurrSelection.Item(m)
    Debug.Print "[" & Date & " " & Time & "] moving #" & m & _
                ": folder = " & folderName & _
                "; subject = " & olCurrMailItem.Subject & "..."
    olCurrMailItem.Move olDestFolder
 Next m

End Sub

Sub Delete()
 MoveToFolder ("Deleted Items")
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line causes that error?

Answer (score 0):

This line is for Outlook 2003. mailboxNameString = "**Mailbox** - David Beach"

Take a look at your 2010 mailbox and use that name.